# Collatz sequence in C

Tags: beginner, c, collatz-sequence

First of all, if you're unfamiliar with the Collatz sequence, it recursively applies the following function to an integer:

$$ f(n) =  \begin{cases} n/2 & \text{if } n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}, \\ 3n+1 & \text{if } n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}. \end{cases} $$

What I wanted to do was to make a program that would:

- Quit if 0 was inputted
- Reprompt the user if something invalid was inputted
- For positive integers, e.g. 7, output "7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1"
- For negative integers, e.g. -3, where doing the above would output "-3 -8 -4 -2 -1 -2 -1 -2... [forever repeating]", output something like "-3 -8 -4 (-2 -1)", as "-2 -1" repeats forever.

This is what I have, which fits most of the criteria, but could definitely be improved somehow. What do you guys think?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
long long cltz(long long x);

int main() {
    long long n;
    char input[256];
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a positive or negative integer (0 to quit): ");
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL) break;
        if (sscanf(input, "%lld", &n) != 1) continue;
        if (n == 0) break;
        bool sign = n < 0;
        long long on = n, slow = n, fast = n;
        while (sign) {
            slow = cltz(slow);
            fast = cltz(cltz(fast));
            if (fast == slow) break;
        }
        if (on == slow && sign) printf("( ");
        printf("%lld ", n);
        while (n != 1) {
            n = cltz(n);
            if (n == slow) break;
            printf("%lld ", n);
        }
        long long c_slow = cltz(slow);
        if (sign && on != slow) {
            printf("( %lld ", slow);
            while (c_slow != slow) {
                printf("%lld ", c_slow);
                c_slow = cltz(c_slow);
            }
            printf(")");
        }
        if (on == slow && sign) printf(")");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
long long cltz(long long x) {
    return (x & 1) ? ((x << 1) + x + 1) : (x >> 1);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want the negative loop marked as `(-2 -1)` but not the positive loop `4 2 1`?

Comment: Does `cltz` just stand for Collatz?  I thought at first it was some bithack helper function since the name is very close to `clz` (count leading zeros) and `ctz` (count trailing zeros).  Or clear trailing zeros?  But that doesn't make sense because clearing means zeroing.  Anyway, see [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written asm?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) re: versions that will compile efficiently for x86, specifically that using an unsigned type (`uint64_t`) was faster there, using `/2` which has to truncate toward 0 for signed, unlike `>>1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Let the compile optimize**

Rather than `(x << 1) + x + 1) : (x >> 1)`, use `(x*3 + 1) : (x/2)` to match the algorithm and enable your compiler's optimizations.

If you can optimize better than the compiler, get a better compiler.

Note that `x%2` is  *not* the same as `x mod 2`.
Stay with `x & 1` or use `x % 2llu`.

**Detect overflow**

`cltz()` may overflow.  Should you want to detect this:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Highest odd value valid for `cltz()`
#define CLTX_ODD_HIGH ((LLONG_MAX - 1)/3)

long long cltz(long long x) {
  // return (x & 1) ? ((x << 1) + x + 1) : (x >> 1);
  if (x & 1) {
    if (llabs(x) > CLTX_ODD_HIGH) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Overflow with %lld\n", x); 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return x*3 + 1;
  }
  return x / 2;  
}
```

**Design**

Consider `bool sign = n < 0; ...  if (on == slow && sign) printf(")"); printf("\n");` as a helper function.  That is, separate user input from doing the task.

Easier to perform testing and recover from overflow.

Comment: Do you say that `x%2` is not the same as mathematical `x` mod 2 because the result is different for negative numbers?  Whilst that's true in general, we're in a boolean context here (i.e. implicitly `x&2 != 0`), for which the result should be the same, and a compiler may be able to produce identical code (though I haven't confirmed that the ones I care about actually do).

Comment: @TobySpeight Agree that `if (x%2)` is like `if (x&1)` if `x` in `unsigned` or `signed` (aside from the so to be gone non- 2's complement).  IAC, _mod_ and signed `%` are a general source of errors given `-1%2 --> -1`.

Comment: Using `x/2` instead of `x>>1` would make the code slower unless you also change `x` from `long long` to `unsigned long long`.  See [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978).  That would also sidestep the whole `%2` issue @TobySpeight discussed.  (Although compilers *are* smart enough to optimize `x%2 != 0` the same as `x&1` even for signed types, the problem is only when code insists on writing `x%2 == 1` that forces compilers to make asm such that it's false for negative odd integers.)

Comment: Oh, I read the question more carefully and see they are actually playing with negative starting values for the sequence.  In general `x/2` (truncating toward zero) is not equivalent to `x>>1` (rounding toward -inf), but interestingly in this case it's only done on even numbers, so either works.  But GCC and clang don't notice that, and do the full rounding correction using `shr reg, 63` / `add` before `sar`: https://godbolt.org/z/osT5c94Ph  So your version is less efficient.  `x*3+1` is good, though; compilers know how to split it into `x*2 + x` for an x86 LEA, no need to do that manually.

Comment: "If you can optimize better than the compiler, get a better compiler." this should be told in class.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to chux's review:

## Naming things

Avoid unnecessarily abbreviating variable and function names. Some use of single-letter variables is OK, like `i` for a loop index, or `n` for a count.

Since `n` is not a count but just the current value, I would write `current` or `value`. I know that it is used in the mathematical definition of the Collatz sequence, but unless you add a comment explaining this and showing that function, then a reader of your code has no idea what `n` means.

Instead of `cltz` and `c`, write `collatz`. Instead of `o`, write `old_value` or `previous` (depending on whether you renamed `n` to `value` or `current`).

## Don't special-case negative integers

If you rewrite your code to always check if there is a repetition, you don't need to look at the sign bit. I would have a small array of two entries to remember the past two values. This also avoids making more calls to `cltz()` than necessary: you are calculating `fast` only to check if there is a repetition, but then you discard it even though you'll recalculate the same value soon afterwards.

Fill the array first, then calculate a new value every step, check if there is a repetition, if not print the oldest value in the array and replace it with the newly calculated one. If there is a repetition, then you can print the parentheses and the two values in the array, as those will be the repeating ones.